# Internal Server Error when echoing an OBJECT from wp ajax action function in functions.php to JS file

Tags: custom-post-types, ajax, internal-server-error

I'm using Elementor Pro as my page builder. I'm trying to create a Job Post filter using Elementor forms. Issue is when I echo and return an Object type from the functions.php file to the JS file. It gives out an Internal Server Error 500. I want to know how I can pass the whole post object instead of sending Title, excerpt, image separately.

JS code

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#jobs_filter_form').submit(function(){
        filter = $('#jobs_filter_form');
        let keywords = $('#form-field-job_keywords').val();
        let location = $('#form-field-job_location').val();
        let category = $('#form-field-job_category').val();
        $.ajax({
            url:'http://localhost/placementpro/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            data:{
                'action': 'filter_jobs',
                'keywords': keywords,
                'location': location,
                'category': category,
            },
            type:'POST',
            beforeSend:function(xhr){
                filter.find('button').text('Processing...'); // changing the button label
            },
            success:function(data){
                filter.find('button').text('Apply filter'); // changing the button label back
                $('#filtered_jobs').html(data);
            },
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

PHP code

```
add_action('wp_ajax_filter_jobs', 'filter_jobs_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_jobs', 'filter_jobs_function');

function filter_jobs_function(){
    $keywords = $_POST['keywords'];    
    $location = $_POST['location'];    
    $category = $_POST['category'];
        
    $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'kuwjr_job',
        'cache_results'     => false,
        'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
        'update_post_term_cache' => false,
        'fields'            => 'all',
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'    => 12,
        'orderby'           => 'date',
        'order'             => 'DESC',
        's'                 => $keywords,
        'meta_query'        => array(
            array(
                'key'   => 'location',
                'value' => $location,
            ),
        ),
        'tax_query'         => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'job-category',
                'terms'     => $category,
                'field'     => 'name',
            ),
        ),
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( $query->have_posts() ):
        while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
            echo $query->post;
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    else :
        echo 'No posts found';
    endif;

    die();
}
```

Comment: ***you can't echo an object***, that's also not how you get the current post in a loop, you need to use `get_post()` not `$query->post`. If you want to return object data as JSON you have to JSON encode it, but why build this with the old legacy admin ajax and a custom handler when you can query the REST API that already exists? Have you tried looking at `yoursite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/kuwjr_job` and passing parameters to it?

Comment: Hi @Tom, I'm just a beginner to wp. I tried http://localhost/placementpro/wp-json/wp/v2/kuwjr_job but it says `rest_no_route`. I'm trying to create a Job posts filter. Btw kuwjr_job is a cpt. I'm following this tutorial: https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/ajax-post-filters.html

Comment: add the `show_in_rest` option to your custom taxonomy and set it to true, then resave your permalink settings and it should appear. Note that the problem you asked about isn't necessarily a WordPress problem but a fundamental PHP issue. It would be like it I told you to read the items in a list out loud, but instead of paper with text I gave you a mouldy banana, it would make no sense and PHP is basically saying the same thing to you right now. Also not all tutorials are correct or do things in the best way

Comment: The mouldy banana was very helpful, If I use the REST API and retrieve posts still I'll be receiving JSON data, it would be easier if there was a way to output the post object directly to html without having to create a template file (since I'm already using elementor)